# Python: Fastest Way to compare arrays elementwise

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I am looking for the fastest way to output the index of the first difference of two arrays in Python. For example, let's take the following two arrays:

```
test1 = [1, 3, 5, 8]
test2 = [1]
test3 = [1, 3]
```

Comparing `test1` and `test2`, I would like to output `1`, while the comparison of test1 and test3 should output `2`.

In other words I look for an equivalent to the statement:

```
import numpy as np
np.where(np.where(test1 == test2, test1, 0) == '0')[0][0]
```

with varying array lengths.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: No, the elements are not sorted. I tried various numpy statements so far

Comment: Are they actually numpy arrays or lists?

Comment: Originally they are lists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For lists this works:

```
from itertools import zip_longest

def find_first_diff(list1, list2):
    for index, (x, y) in enumerate(zip_longest(list1, list2, 
                                               fillvalue=object())):
        if x != y:
            return index
```

`zip_longest` pads the shorter list with `None` or with a provided fill value. The standard `zip` does not work if the difference is caused by different list lengths rather than actual different values in the lists.

On Python 2 use `izip_longest`.

Updated: Created unique fill value to avoid potential problems with `None` as list value. `object()` is unique:

```
>>> o1 = object()
>>> o2 = object()
>>> o1 == o2
False
```

This pure Python approach **might** be faster than a NumPy solution. This depends on the actual data and other circumstances.

1. Converting a list into a NumPy array also takes time. This might actually
   take longer than finding the index with the function above. If you are not
   going to use the NumPy array for other calculations, the conversion
   might cause considerable overhead.
2. NumPy always searches the full array. If the difference comes early,
   you do a lot more work than you need to.
3. NumPy creates a bunch of intermediate arrays. This costs memory and time.
4. NumPy needs to construct intermediate arrays with the maximum length.
   Comparing many small with very large arrays is unfavorable here.

In general, in many cases NumPy is faster than a pure Python solution.
But each case is a bit different and there are situations where pure
Python is faster.

Comment: This works reliably only if the lists are guaranteed to never contain `None`.  `find_first_diff([1],[1,None])` for instance doesn't correctly return `1`.

Comment: @L3viathan Thanks for the hint. My update should fix this. Since NumPy arrays are homogenous in terms of type, I assumed integer or float-only arrays/lists.

Comment: @Mike see my edit answer below. Your method **is** faster if the arrays need to be converted to numpy. But my method is much faster if they're already converted - as you say it depends on the whole problem. Often it's better to do everything in numpy is speed is going to become an issue

Answer (score 4):

with numpy arrays (which will be faster for big arrays) then you could check the lengths of the lists then (also) check the overlapping parts something like the following (obviously slicing the longer to the length of the shorter):

```
import numpy as np

n = min(len(test1), len(test2))
x = np.where(test1[:n] != test2[:n])[0]
if len(x) > 0:
  ans = x[0]
elif len(test1) != len(test2):
  ans = n
else:
  ans = None
```

EDIT - despite this being voted down I will leave my answer up here in case someone else needs to do something similar.

If the starting arrays are large and numpy then **this is the fastest method**. Also I had to modify Andy's code to get it to work. In the order: 1. my suggestion, 2. Paidric's (now removed but the most elegant), 3. Andy's accepted answer, 4. zip - non numpy, 5. vanilla python without zip as per @leekaiinthesky

**0.1ms**, 9.6ms, 0.6ms, 2.8ms, 2.3ms

if the conversion to ndarray is included in timeit then the **non-numpy nop-zip method is fastest**

7.1ms, 17.1ms, 7.7ms, 2.8ms, **2.3ms**

and even more so if the difference between the two lists is at around index 1,000 rather than 10,000

7.1ms, 17.1ms, 7.7ms, 0.3ms, **0.2ms**

```
import timeit

setup = """
import numpy as np
from itertools import zip_longest
list1 = [1 for i in range(10000)] + [4, 5, 7]
list2 = [1 for i in range(10000)] + [4, 4]
test1 = np.array(list1)
test2 = np.array(list2)

def find_first_diff(l1, l2):
    for index, (x, y) in enumerate(zip_longest(l1, l2, fillvalue=object())):
        if x != y:
            return index

def findFirstDifference(list1, list2):
  minLength = min(len(list1), len(list2))
  for index in range(minLength):
    if list1[index] != list2[index]:
      return index
  return minLength
"""

fn = ["""
n = min(len(test1), len(test2))
x = np.where(test1[:n] != test2[:n])[0]
if len(x) > 0:
  ans = x[0]
elif len(test1) != len(test2):
  ans = n
else:
  ans = None""",
"""
x = np.where(np.in1d(list1, list2) == False)[0]
if len(x) > 0:
  ans = x[0]
else:
  ans = None""",
"""
x = test1
y = np.resize(test2, x.shape)
x = np.where(np.where(x == y, x, 0) == 0)[0]
if len(x) > 0:
  ans = x[0]
else:
  ans = None""",
"""
ans = find_first_diff(list1, list2)""",
"""
ans = findFirstDifference(list1, list2)"""]

for f in fn:
  print(timeit.timeit(f, setup, number = 1000))
```

Comment: Thanks! +1 for the timing comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest algorithm would compare every element up to the first difference and no more. So iterating through the two lists pairwise like that would give you this:

```
def findFirstDifference(list1, list2):
  minLength = min(len(list1), len(list2))
  for index in xrange(minLength):
    if list1[index] != list2[index]:
      return index
  return minLength # the two lists agree where they both have values, so return the next index
```

Which gives the output you want:

```
print findFirstDifference(test1, test3)
> 2
```

Comment: This doesn't always work if the first list is shorter than the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Here one way to do it:

```
from itertools import izip
def compare_lists(lista, listb):
    """
    Compare two lists and return the first index where they differ. if
    they are equal, return the list len
    """
    for position, (a, b) in enumerate(zip(lista, listb)):
        if a != b:
            return position
    return min([len(lista), len(listb)])
```

- The algorithm is simple: `zip` (or in this case, a more efficient `izip`) the two lists, then compare them element by element.
- The `eumerate` function gives the index position which we can return if a discrepancy found
- If we exit the `for` loop without any returns, one of the two possibilities can happen:

  1. The two lists are identical. In this case, we want to return the length of either lists.
  2. Lists are of different length and they are equal up to the length of the shorter list. In this case, we want to return the length of the shorter list

  In ether cases, the `min(...)` expression is what we want.
- This function has a bug: if you compare two empty lists, it returns 0, which seems wrong. I'll leave it to you to fix it as an exercise.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all of your suggestions, I just found a much simpler way for my problem which is:

```
x = numpy.array(test1)
y = np.resize(numpy.array(test2), x.shape)
np.where(np.where(x == y, x, 0) == '0')[0][0]
```

Comment: Try `test1 = [3, 4, 3, 5]` and `test2 = [3, 4]` with your approach. Also, check with `test1 = [3, 4, 3, 4]` and `test2 = [3, 4]`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an admittedly not very pythonic, numpy-free stab:

```
b = zip (test1, test2)
c = 0
while b:        
    b = b[1:]
    if not b or b[0][0] != b[0][1]:
        break
    else:
        c = c + 1
print c
```

Answer (score 0):

For Python 3.x:

```
  def first_diff_index(ls1, ls2):
    l = min(len(ls1), len(ls2)) 
    return next((i for i in range(l) if ls1[i] != ls2[i]), l)
```

(for Python 2.7 onwards substitute `range` by `xrange`)